# Linux Markdown editor that supports inline images, pandoc syntax and vim-keybindings?

Tags: linux, text-editor, markdown, vim

I am looking for for a Markdown editor that can display inline images, is largely compatible with pandoc syntax, supports most common vim-keybindings, and runs on Linux.

I am currently using `gvim` with `vim-pandoc` for syntax highlighting, but there is no support for displaying images inside `gvim`. Newer markdown editors like [Abricotine](https://github.com/brrd/Abricotine), looks great and can display inline images, but I can't find one that supports vim-bindings or most of the pandoc spec.

The closest I have found is to [preview the document in a separate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212340/is-there-a-vim-plugin-for-preview-markdown-file), but I would prefer to be able to display and edit the content (including images) in one window instead of in two different windows

**Update 2021-03-03** I use markdown both for notetaking and writing longer articles, so it would be ideal with a program that is nimble yet capable (like vim), rather than a full blown IDE, but I'm open to suggestions for either.

Comment: Have you checked [other pandoc questions tagged `markdown`](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[markdown]+pandoc), especially [those with answers](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[markdown]+pandoc+answers%3A1)? Doesn't any of their solution fit your requirements?

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, most of those are about mac or web markdown editors, or markdown conversion tools. The closest I have found is to [preview the document in a separate window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212340/is-there-a-vim-plugin-for-preview-markdown-file), but I would prefer to be able to display and edit the content (including images) in one window instead of in two different windows.

Comment: Thanks for checking! May I suggest you [edit] that into your question, so it becomes obvious to potential answerers? Not everybody scans comments ;) I've tried a bunch of those editors, but I didn't check for pandoc&vim so I cannot give a recommendation here myself. However, I didn't encounter any editor not having a *separate* window for the preview, so I'm afraid it already fails at this place. Though I've not explicitly checked for that (I'm fine with seeing the Markdown I write).

Comment: Have you tried haroopad?

Comment: @sebelk yes, last time I used it there was no support for inline images rendered in the editor. Has that changed?

Comment: @cheflo do you say something like: ```![Alt Text](http://bit.ly/1drEdWK "Title")``` ? (v. 0.13.1)

Comment: @sebelk I just took a look at Haroopad again (0.13.1), and it does not support inline rendering, but rather renders images and text in a separate split to the side of the main window. Take a look at [Abricotine](https://github.com/brrd/Abricotine) for comparison to see what inline rendering/preview looks like.

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround, if a little overkill, is to use a [jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) notebook in a browser window - you will get each cell rendered as you go from cell to cell and you could always have a function at the top that saves the *other* notebook cells and renders the document through pandoc.

The majority of the markdown used in jupyter/ipython is the same as the pandoc markdown and I am sure that a little tailoring could support the rest & you can definitely have images embedded.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** After having several issues with emacs, I have switched back to vim for editing md files, which I think is an overall much nicer experience even though it doesn't render images inline ([yet...](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/12991#issuecomment-789545835)).

To improve the image workflow I use the [md-img-paste plugin](https://github.com/ferrine/md-img-paste.vim) and a custom command to open images when clicking them (you could also use `gx` for the default fileviewer):

```
" cd is needed for feh to reload the filelist correctly
nnoremap <leader>I :!cd <cfile>:p:h && feh --scale-down --reload 5 --no-jump-on-resort --start-at <cfile>:t &<CR><CR>
```

I have a few other flags also and use i3 to stack it above my vim window, but they are not technically needed.

---

Original emacs post:

I would never have guessed it at the time I posted this question, but the most suitable editor for my purposes seems to be... Emacs! I recently started using Emacs to try out the feature-filled org-mode for note taking. It turns out that it has all the features I was looking for!

- **Vim bindings** are provided via [evil-mode](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil), which can be configured separately and is installed by default in the [Spacemacs distribution](http://spacemacs.org/) of Emacs (this is what I use, it comes with many nice defaults).
- **Pandoc syntax highlighting** - [Markdown mode](https://github.com/defunkt/markdown-mode) enables syntax highlighting for `pandoc` markup elements (there is also [Pandoc mode](https://github.com/joostkremers/pandoc-mode), which I have not tried myself). It is possible to define custom export commands and view the output in the built-in Emacs browser. Markdown mode also enables folding of headings similar to `vim-pandoc`.
- **Inline-images** - Images can be viewed inline in both Markdown mode and org-mode, as long as imagemagick is installed and supported by your version of Emacs. The functions used in org-mode can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32111919/2166823) (to be fair, I have had some troubles with inline images in markdown mode, but I haven't looked too much into it since I use org-mode for note taking now).

Other aspects I appreciate of Emacs include the possibility to search among existing functions and keybindings and org-mode's time-keeping and task management features. To be clear, I still use vim for editing files via terminal, but for taking notes I use Emacs with org-mode and it's great!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Rstudio or Visual Studio Code

**rstudio**

[rstudio](https://rstudio.com/) Desktop is free and has evolved to a multi-language IDE in recent years.

rstudio assumes that you want to write Markdown in their own dialect [RMarkdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/), which is basically pandoc markdown with  R code chunks embedded by you and denoted with `{r}`.  However you can also edit `.md` files directly. rstudio compiles ("knits") .Rmd via intermediate .md to .html, .docx, and other file types.

There is a [Vim mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208252/how-to-enable-vim-mode-in-rstudio) and you can tell the IDE if you want to display images inline, with a placeholder, or in a preview pane.

rstudio looks for R on startup, so you need to install R first.

**VS Code**

With VSCode comes with good built-in markdown support, you can install [VIm Keybindings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) as an Extension, and also some more Extensions for enhancing the [Markdown Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced) capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I looked at vscode and it is really nice with the [full neovim extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asvetliakov.vscode-neovim), but I think it only offers images in preview panes. I didn't realize RStudio could display markdown images inline, which is a nice feature. I think both are a bit heavy for my notetaking purposes, especially RStudio, but they are nice alternatives to be aware of (and I realize I didn't specify anything about notetaking initially so added it now).

Comment: The built-in Markdown capablities of VSCode get expanded all the time, by the way. Take  another look,  next year.