# Linux Markdown editor with Pandoc export support?

Tags: linux, text-editor, markdown

I am looking for Linux Markdown editors that provide support to export content to various formats using [Pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc).

**Requirements:**

- Provide Ubuntu `deb` package
- Free and open-source
- Support for the basic Markdown specification (however any support for more sophisticated ones such as Markdown Extra would be nice)
- Integrates the independent Pandoc software into the UI of the software so that I don't have to deal with it from the command-line<sup>**1**</sup>

**Not needed (but won't hurt if there):**

- live preview
- keybindings

So far I have found [Ghostwriter](https://github.com/wereturtle/ghostwriter) which looks great and I am curious if there are more.

---

<sup>**1:** though *Pandoc* can be used independently from any editor, I want to have it integrated for easier use.</sup>

Comment: Please take a look at [Linux Markdown editor that supports inline images, pandoc syntax and vim-keybindings?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/30525/185) and [other pandoc questions tagged `markdown`](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarkdown%5D+pandoc) (especially [those with answers](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarkdown%5D+pandoc+answers%3A1)). Also see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) (price tag? What Markdown dialect(s)? Other features?)

Comment: Thank you @Izzy! I improved my question. Moreover I looked at the other questions but none fits my requirements. I don't need a preview or keybindings. The sole Pandoc export functionality is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Could you please specify what you've got in mind with "any kind"? Do you mean "standard Markdown suffices" – or rather "as many dialects as possible"? I for example wouldn't want to go without *Markdown Extra* support (tables, footnotes, attributes), others need *Github flavored" or the SE Markdown. // If it weren't for Pandoc, *ReText* might fit your needs (`.deb`, free/open-source, Markdown/Extra, export to PDF+OO/LO).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Any editor will do. Pandoc runs independently of the editor.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I will give *ReText* a try. Moreover, I specified the question further. I am looking for editors that integrate Pandoc into the UI so that I don't have to deal with it from the command-line. So far I have found [Ghostwriter](https://github.com/wereturtle/ghostwriter) which looks great and I am curious if there are more.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to integration of Markdown/Pandoc within the editor, Emacs with [Markdown mode](https://github.com/defunkt/markdown-mode) would work well (there is also [Pandoc mode](https://github.com/joostkremers/pandoc-mode), which I have not tried myself). Markdown syntax is highlighted, you can bind keys to custom Pandoc export commands, and [view the output document](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27110/markdown-preview-in-emacs-using-pandoc) in the built-in Emacs browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Typora](https://typora.io) is a WYSAWYG (What You See Approximates What You Get) Markdown editor with Pandoc integration.

Answer (score 0):

[Panwriter](https://panwriter.com/) is a simple split-view editor with HTML preview pane (powered by markdown-it with extensions tuned to mimic much of pandoc syntax).

It does some acrobatics to achieve page breaks in HTML preview & export, though those didn't work for me.

But it can also export via pandoc at the press of a key!
Pandoc options can be controlled via YAML metadata, with a new structure that pandoc doesn't understand (but they are harmless when running pandoc directly).